# pyspark code in loop acts different from single executions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The following code hits some jobs with 'job skipped'  after a few times thru the loop, and the df that is read on that iteration by 'myfunc' comes back with 0 rows (but surprisingly, with the correct number of columns) :

```
for i in range(len(dates)-1):
  date1,date2=dates[i],dates[i+1]
  params['file_path'] = ['s3a://path/to/files{}.json'.format(date1),'s3a://path/to/files{}.json'.format(date2)]
  df = myfunc(params)
```

However when I run it 'by hand' several times, all is well - no skipped jobs and df's come back full.

```
date1,date2=dates[0],dates[1]
params['file_path'] = ['s3a://path/to/files{}.json'.format(date1),'s3a://path/to/files{}.json'.format(date2)]
df = myfunc(params)
```

The above runs fine, and when I change to `date1,date2=dates[1],dates[2]` also ok, etc. There aren't very many files and I've already finished them all by hand as above but would like to know what's going on. The filenames generated in the for loop work fine when I copy-paste them into my params.   I am far from expert in spark so let me know if there's something obvious to check.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the code of `myfunc` I can only guess you problem.
Probably the 0 rows issue originates from the assignment `df = myfunc(params)` which will overwrite the `df` all the time and does not append to the previous df. Probably for the last two dates it is just empty.
Skipping jobs usually comes from caching. Are you using caching anywhere?

Comment: i'm not trying to append the df,  i want a new one every iteration.  I know for the last dates its not empty since when I run those by hsnd (not in the loop) I get full dataframes.  I am not knowingly using caching anywhere.

Comment: ...and the only time I get empty df's is when skipped jobs occur

Comment: sonds very strange. Could you please share the code of `myfunc` in the question?